# How is this VB.NET code evaluated?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, boolean, comparison

I am working on a code conversion from VB.NET to C#. I found this piece of code which I am trying to wrap my head around but I can't get how it is evaluated:

```
If eToken.ToLower = False Then _
    Throw New Exception("An eToken is required for this kind of VPN-Permission.)
```

My problem is with the comparison between a string `eToken.ToLower` and a boolean value `False`.

I tried to use a converter and what I got was as follow (which is not a valid statement in C# as you cannot compare a `string` to a `bool`):

```
if (eToken.ToLower() == false) {
    throw new Exception("An eToken is required for this kind of VPN-Permission.");
}
```

Comment: is option strict off?

Comment: It probably does an implicit cast/convert. For instance, if eToken == "True" it doesn't throw an exception in my test.

Comment: Yes, actually. It's a call to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean(String Value)`.

Comment: @DanielA.White yes it is turned off

Comment: You cannot compare a String to a Boolean in VB.NET with Option Strict On.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I compiled it and decompiled the IL; in C# that is:

```
string eToken = "abc"; // from: Dim eToken As String = "abc" in my code 
if (!Conversions.ToBoolean(eToken.ToLower()))
{
    throw new Exception("An eToken is required for this kind of VPN-Permission.");
}
```

So there's your answer: it is using `Conversions.ToBoolean` (where `Conversions` is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions` in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`)

Comment: I will have a add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll (which I am trying yo avoid) to use that but thank you for pointing it out. I can extract the code from it.

Comment: It will end up returning `CBool(eToken)`. I think the C# equivalent would be `String.IsNullOrEmpty(eToken)`

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou well, it runs what is shown; if `CBool(foo)` is equivalent to `Conversions.ToBoolean(foo)`, then: sure. And no, that is **not** the same as `string.IsNullOrEmpty` - it checks for the literal `"True"` / `"False"` strings: http://pastie.org/9829529

Comment: System.Convert.ToBoolean is a pretty good replacement (as noted by Siva) - most people are not going to want to use Micorosoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean from C#, especially when Convert.ToBoolean comes so close.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a type cast assuming, eToken has a value of "true"/"false":

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(eToken.ToLower())==false)
    throw new Exception("An eToken is required for this kind of VPN-Permission.");
}
```

Comment: Also what this does `Convert.ToBoolean(eToken.ToLower()==false)`? Do you mean `Convert.ToBoolean(eToken.ToLower())==false` ?